# Unable to compile IEEE754 intel library

Tags: c++, compilation, calculator

I am stuggling with IEEE754 intel library which I want to use in my calculator project on Raspberry pico. I want to compute with 128-bit decimal floating-point numbers.

This library is quite large for Raspberry pico so I planned to use only source files with functions I need (+, -, *, /, sqrt, sin, cos, log, ...).

It is this library:
[IEE754 intel library](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library.html)

First I managed to make to work `add`, `sub`, `mul`, `div` and `sqrt`. 
This files are needed:

- bid128.c
- bid128_2_str.h
- bid128_2_str_macros.h
- bid128_2_str_tables.c
- bid128_add.c
- bid128_fma.c
- bid128_mul.c
- bid128_sqrt.c
- bid128_string.c
- bid_conf.h
- bid_decimal_data.c
- bid_functions.h
- bid_internal.h
- bid_round.c
- bid_sqrt_macros.h
- bid_trans.h
- decimal.h

And here is the code:

```
#include "decimal.h"

BID_UINT128 a, b, c;

char output_IEEE[] = " ";

_IDEC_round my_rnd_mode = _IDEC_dflround;
_IDEC_flags my_fpsf = _IDEC_allflagsclear;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  delay(5000);

  char input_a[] = {'+', '0', '.', '1', '2', 'E', '-', '1', '2', 0};
  char input_b[] = {'3', '.', '1', '4', '1', 0};

  a = __bid128_from_string (input_a, my_rnd_mode, &my_fpsf);
  __bid128_to_string (output_IEEE, a, &my_fpsf); 
  Serial.println("a = " + String(output_IEEE)); 

  b = __bid128_from_string (input_b, my_rnd_mode, &my_fpsf);
  __bid128_to_string (output_IEEE, b, &my_fpsf); 
  Serial.println("b = " + String(output_IEEE)); 
  
  my_rnd_mode = _IDEC_nearesteven; my_fpsf = _IDEC_allflagsclear; 

  c = __bid128_add (a, b, my_rnd_mode, &my_fpsf);
  __bid128_to_string (output_IEEE, c, &my_fpsf); 
  Serial.println("a + b = " + String(output_IEEE)); 
  
   c = __bid128_mul (a, b, my_rnd_mode, &my_fpsf);
  __bid128_to_string (output_IEEE, c, &my_fpsf); 
  Serial.println("a * b = " + String(output_IEEE)); 

  c = __bid128_sqrt (a, my_rnd_mode, &my_fpsf);
  __bid128_to_string (output_IEEE, c, &my_fpsf); 
  Serial.println("sqrt(a) = " + String(output_IEEE)); 

}
```

I get this output which is exactly what I want:

> a = +12E-14
> b = +3141E-3
> a + b = +314100000000012E-14
> a * b = +37692E-17 sqrt(a) = +3464101615137754587054892683011745E-40

but when I want to compute transcendental with this file *bid128_sin.c* added:

```
  c = __bid128_sin (a, my_rnd_mode, &my_fpsf);
  __bid128_to_string (output_IEEE, c, &my_fpsf); 
  Serial.println("sqrt(a) = " + String(output_IEEE));
```

I must include a lot of another source files and headers and the more I add the more errors arise.
Has someone experience with this library, please. I don't want to compile the whole library because it would be too big for the raspberry pico. I am also unable to get those "*transcendental*" functions to work on windows.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with this library, but quickly looking at it, it comes with a makefile. You would ideally *build* the library and use it as a library instead of compiling the library's source files as part of your project. If you DO want to compile these sources alongside your project (for whatever reasons) you should add every single one of them.

Comment: Yes, I know that there is a makefile. But as I mentioned I don't want to compile the whole library because I don't need all functions and it would also have 4MB in size which wouldn't fit into paspberry pico with 2MB flash. I am just "hobby" programmer, my primary interest is HW development so my skills are not so high. But I know that this lib is used in this great calc: https://www.swissmicros.com/product/dm42. It has ARM inside so it shoul be possible to compile it for ARM.

Comment: The linking process does not bring in the whole library, it only grabs what you use. That's not an issue.

Comment: Yes, I know that. And it works unless I want to add functions like sin, log, ... Then it requires source files from directory /float128 and I get a lot of errors. And it also becomes architecture dependent as I must include "architecture.h". And there is no choice of ARM. I am not able to compile it also for windows.